# Sum of time for each user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so I have a table where each `user_id` has `operation_timestamp`. To check how long action took for each `user_id` I use query `max(operation_timestamp)-min(operation_timestamp)` which then I convert to decimals so let say I get result of:

```
  SHIFT   USER ID       MIN         MAX       MAX-MIN    DECIMAL
  shift1  user_1     08:19:42    09:55:20    01:35:37     1.59
  shift2  user_2     10:04:27    10:28:22    00:23:54     0.40
  shift2  user_3     10:44:07    10:55:58    00:01:51     0.04
  shift2  user_4     06:25:33    10:51:52    04:26:19     4.44
```

Now my question: **how can I work out a sum of time in decimals so I have a total time spend on activity for all users?** Something like this:

```
 SHIFT     TOTAL_DECIMAL
  shift1        1.59
  shift2        4.88
```

I have tried same query but without `group by user_id` function but it is then calculating max and min without looking at separate user_id, so let say it will calculate `shift2` totals as `06:25:33 (user_4) to 10:55:58 (user_3)` which would give a result of `4.45` in decimals.

This is the query I use without success:

```
select
case 
when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '00:00:00.000' and '05:59:59.000' then 'Nights'
when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '06:00:00.000' and '13:59:59.000' then 'Days'
when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '14:00:00.000' and '21:59:59.000' then 'Lates'
when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '22:00:00.000' and '23:59:59.000' then 'Nights'
else 'other'
end as shift,
a.userid,
substr(min(a.operation_ts),11,9),
substr(max(a.operation_ts),11,9),
substr((max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)),10,9) as time_on_go,
round(((substr((max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)),11,2))*3600+(substr((max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)),14,2))*60+(substr((max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)),17,2)))/3600,2) time_decimal
from dc_sys_common:user_operation a
where a.activity_code = 1012
and date(a.operation_ts) between today and today+1
and SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,9) between '00:00:00' and '21:59:59'
group by userid, shift
having max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)>'0 00:00:01.000'
order by shift asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the GROUP BY SHIFT on your first query being nested:

```
SELECT `SHIFT`, SUM(`DECIMAL`)
FROM
(
    -- your query here
)
GROUP BY `SHIFT`
```

Comment: Tried it but it gives me an error:
  `Cannot have aggregates within aggregates.`

Comment: It should work and from what you explained thats the way to go. Edit your question and add your actual query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two levels of aggregation for what you want to do, one at the level of `user_id` and `shift` and the second at the level of `shift`:

```
select shift, 
from (select case when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '00:00:00.000' and '05:59:59.000' then 'Nights'
                  when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '06:00:00.000' and '13:59:59.000' then 'Days'
                  when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '14:00:00.000' and '21:59:59.000' then 'Lates'
                  when SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,13) between '22:00:00.000' and '23:59:59.000' then 'Nights'
                  else 'other'
             end) as shift,
             a.userid,
             round(((substr((max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)),11,2))*3600+(substr((max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)),14,2))*60+(substr((max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)),17,2)))/3600,2
                  ) time_decimal
      from dc_sys_common:user_operation a
      where a.activity_code = 1012 and
            date(a.operation_ts) between today and today+1 and
            SUBSTR(a.operation_ts,12,9) between '00:00:00' and '21:59:59'
      group by userid, shift
      having max(a.operation_ts)-min(a.operation_ts)>'0 00:00:01.000'
     ) us
group by shift asc;
```